# Prove that $Av_i \bullet Av_j = v_i \bullet v_j$, $\forall i,j$

Tags: linear-algebra

There are $2$ different bases in $R^2$, $\{u_1,u_2\} , \{v_1,v_2\}$. and $A$ is a matrix $nxn$.

Is it possible to prove that

> If(**Given**) $Au_i \bullet Au_j = u_i \bullet u_j$, $\forall i,j$.
>
> Then(**Prove**) $Av_i \bullet Av_j = v_i \bullet v_j$, $\forall i,j$

If yes, I'd like to know how can I prove that. I've no idea how to approach this.

Comment: Given any vector $u,$ how does $Au \cdot Au$ compare with $u \cdot u?$

Comment: @WillJagy If $A$ is orthogonal matrix?

Comment: Maybe. Just take your $A$ and $u = r u_1 + s u_2$ and carefully write out both  $Au \cdot Au$ and $u \cdot u.$ These will be expressions involving the real coefficients $r,s.$

Comment: @WillJagy I don't know how to expand that in a way that will show me how to prove that. and also, is it possible to prove that?

Comment: @user251257 all that is required is that the expression for $Au \cdot Au$ come out the same as $u \cdot u.$ Having a mixed product will not be a problem.

Comment: @WillJagy Oh it's one of the linear mapping defined uniquely on a basis exercise. My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express $v_i=a_{i1}u_1+a_{i2}u_2$. Now by using that $\bullet$ is bilinear, i.e. $(a+b)\bullet c=a\bullet c+b\bullet c$ we get:

\begin{eqnarray}
Av_i\bullet Av_j&=&(a_{i1}Au_1+a_{i2}Au_2)\bullet (a_{j1}Au_1+a_{j2}Au_2)\\
&=& a_{i1}Au_1\bullet a_{j1}Au_1+a_{i2}Au_2\bullet a_{j1}Au_1+a_{i1}Au_1\bullet a_{j2}Au_2+a_{i2}Au_1\bullet a_{j2}Au_2\\
&=&a_{i1}u_1\bullet a_{j1}u_1+a_{i2}u_2\bullet a_{j1}u_1+a_{i1}u_1\bullet a_{j2}u_2+a_{i2}u_1\bullet a_{j2}u_2\\
&=&(a_{i1}u_1+a_{i2}u_2)\bullet a_{j1}u_1+(a_{i1}u_1+a_{i2}u_2)\bullet a_{j2}u_2\\
&=&(a_{i1}u_1+a_{i2}u_2)\bullet (a_{j1}u_1+a_{j2}u_2)\\
&=& v_i\bullet v_j
\end{eqnarray}
which is what we wanted.

Comment: This is brilliant. Do you have any ideas how can I give a counter example for: Given, $||Au_i|| = ||u_i|| \forall i$, Then, $ ||Av_i|| = ||v_i|| \forall i$?

Comment: Take $$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \sqrt{1/2}\\ 0 & \sqrt{1/2}  \end{pmatrix} $$. Take $u_1=(1,0)$ and $u_2=(0,1)$. Then $\Vert A u_i \Vert= \Vert u_i \Vert$. Now take $v_1=(1,0) $ and  $v_2=(1,1)$ and calculate that $\Vert A v_2\Vert\neq \Vert v_2 \Vert$.

Comment: can you please explain the last equation in your answer, why it equals to $v_i \bullet v_j$ ?

Comment: I just use linearity of the $\bullet $ in every component. I'll add a few steps in the answer.

Comment: @Mail I'll really appreciate it, thank you! Sorry for my stupidity. :(

Comment: And thanks for the counter example, looks awesome!

Comment: You're very welcome! And also I think it is best to write it out on paper by yourself.

Comment: Maik, that is exactly what I did now. Thank you!!!